# mouse x +1 = movieclip timeline frame number + 1

Tags: flash, actionscript, mousemove

I am trying to achieve this on flash

Mouse move x +1 = movieclip timeline frame number +1
&
Mouse move x -1 = movieclip timeline frame number -1

nothing more and nothing less, I thought it would have been an easy thing to do but I couldn't find a solution to this anywhere

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated
thx

Comment: What did you try so far? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: whats About programming itself ? The Documentation of Flash is awesome, You should find there what you Need. Look for "Event Enterframe", that will you need, for catching the mouse movement. Then look for gotoAndStop. You should replace the framenumber by a variable you handle out from the Position. The rest is math, and easy to solve. Try it on your own.


if you have your first Code, post it here, and i ll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would need to listen to the mouse event to get the x coordinate: (see https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html)

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.*;

public class MouseExample extends Sprite {
    public function MouseExample() {
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    }

    private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        mMovieClip.trace(event.localX);
    }
}
```

In the mouseMoveHandler, you would then be able to set the frame of the MovieClip relative to that x coordinate: (see https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop() )

```
mMovieClip.gotoAndStop(mc1.currentFrame + 5);
```

Meaning that the complete code would look something like:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.*;

public class MouseExample extends Sprite {
    var mMovieClip:MovieClip;
    public function MouseExample(movieClip:MovieClip) {
       mMovieClip = movieClip;
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    }

    private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        mMovieClip.gotoAndStop(Math.floor(event.localX));
    }
}
```

Hope that this is useful, I'm not 100% sure about the syntax as I wrote it directly here in the browser and I haven't written ActionScript for about 4/5 years. Good luck.